# Drawing stroke inside of path with Android Graphics

Tags: android, kotlin, graphics, path, stroke

I am using Android Graphics to draw shapes onto a view. I have some Path and what I want to achieve is to have a stroke on the inside along the edges of that path. Unfortunately, Paint.Style.STROKE allows no control over where the stroke is placed. The stroke is always half inside and half outside of the path. Is there any workaround to achieve what I want?

Comment: Calculate what the path would be if shifted inward by half a stroke width